# Fancy indexing of a numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose i have an array shaped as `a`:

```
import numpy as np
n = 10
d = 5
a = np.zeros(shape = np.repeat(n,d))
```

And that I want to obtain the values corresponding to indexes `(0,...,:,...,0)` for the `:` along dimensions, resulting in a `(n,d)`-shaped array `b`, with `b[i,j] = a[0,...,0,i,0,...,0]` where the `i` is in the `j`th dimension.

How can i extract`b` from `a` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the flattened indices and just index for a vectorized solution -

```
n = len(a)
d = a.ndim
idxs = np.multiply.outer(n**np.arange(d), np.arange(n))
out = a.flat[idxs]
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is to do a `for` loop:

```
# get the first slice of `a` along given dimension `j`
def get_slice(a,j):
    idx = [0]*len(a.shape)
    idx[j] = slice(None)
    return a[tuple(idx)]

out = np.stack([get_slice(a,j) for j in range(len(a.shape))])
```

And `out.shape` is `(10,5)`

Comment: Yes that looks like what i already have, but i was looking for a non-looping numpy solution ^^